# SwiftUI: TabView and NavigationView play nicely on iPhone but not on iPad?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, swiftui

My app has a home screen showing a list of options and a few entirely different pages. Each leads to a dispatcher view with a tag indicating which page to show. I also want to be able to swipe between the pages. So I have this code (hugely simplified from the actual app, of course, but behaving in the same way):

```
struct Tab: Hashable {
    let name: String
    let id: Int
}


struct ContentView: View {
    
    let tabs: [Tab] = [Tab(name: "first", id: 1), Tab(name: "second", id: 2), Tab(name: "third", id: 3)]
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                List (tabs, id: \.self) { tab in
                    NavigationLink(destination: Dispatcher(which: tab.id)) {
                        VStack (alignment: .leading) {
                            Text(tab.name).font(.headline).bold()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }.navigationTitle("test")
            Text("hello")
        }
    }
}

struct Dispatcher: View {
    var which: Int
    @State private var tab = 2
    
    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $tab) {
            Text("first page").tag(1)
            Text("second page").tag(2)
            Text("third page").tag(3)
        }
        .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle(indexDisplayMode: .never))
        .onAppear(perform: { tab = which })

    }
}
```

On an iPhone, it works fine. But on an iPad, in either orientation, tapping any option in the home page takes me to the same sub-page, the one set by the initial value of the @State variable tab. The assignment in .onAppear is being executed, but the new value of tab is being ignored.

Any ideas gratefully received.

Jeremy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why not just do this:

```
struct Dispatcher: View {
    @State var which: Int
    
    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $which) {
            Text("first page").tag(1)
            Text("second page").tag(2)
            Text("third page").tag(3)
        }
        .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle(indexDisplayMode: .never))
    }
}
```

Comment: A light-hearted and self-deprecating, appreciative comment I made a couple of days ago in thanks for this answer has disppeared. I'm new here: is there a reason?

Answer (score 0):

Now that workingdog has answered my question, can I perhaps expand it?

I implement his (or her, of course) solution on the iPad. I click on a selection in the NavigationView list (say, "second"). The clicked line highlights and the second page appears.

I then swipe to show another page (say "third"). That's fine.

But "second" remains highlighted in the NavigationView list, so I can't click on it to return to the second page.

Can I tell the NavigationView list to highlight the entry corresponding to the actual shown page? Or to highlight nothing?

Comment: In case you post any more questions, please know that extensions of the original question should be placed as edits, and not as answers  :)